# CLLocation to CLLocationCoordinate2D in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi had lot of trouble in understanding the declaration part in swift programming.
I have line of code `CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate = myLocation.coordinate;`
As same as I declared in Swift programming but I'm getting error

```
var location1:CLLocation! = locationManager1.location
var coordinate1:CLLocationCoordinate2D = location1.coordinate
```

fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

Comment: What error are you getting? Where is the declaration of `location1`?

Comment: I have edited the question ..Can u please check it

Comment: what is `locationManager1`?

Comment: CLLocationManager @Kreiri

Answer (score 24):

the `location1` can be `nil`, and you have to check whether or not it is `nil` before you access to its proprties, like e.g. this:

```
let locationManager1: CLLocationManager // your location manager

// ...

if let location1: CLLocation = locationManager1.location {
    var coordinate1: CLLocationCoordinate2D = location1.coordinate

    // ... proceed with the location and coordintes

} else {
    println("no location...")
}
```